# Hide / Show toggle button doesn't start with content hidden

Tags: javascript, html

It works but it doesn't start off with my 'more details' content toggled to hidden. It starts off with the content showing. I have rewritten this 10 times and can't figure it out.

```js
function toggle() {
  let Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');

  if (Text.style.display == "none") {
    Text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    Text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="moreDetails">

  <h3> 001 </h3>

  <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>

  <h4> N00DS </h4>

</div>

<button title="Click to Show" type="button" onclick="toggle()">MoreDetails</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add style display none to your div id moreDetails

```
<div id="moreDetails" style="display: none">
```

or you can use like this also

```
<script>
function toggle(){
    let Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');

    if(Text.style.display == "none"){
        Text.style.display= "block";
    }
    else {
        Text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
document.getElementById("moreDetails").style.display = "none";
 
</script>
```

or you can use
ternary operator

```
<script>
    function toggle(){
        const Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');
        Text.style.display = Text.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("moreDetails").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Comment: ahh, i think I attempting the second but deleted it in frustration without checking to see if it worked. I think I prefer this method.

Comment: yeah, if this help to you, don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: If I need multiple of these drop downs, how would I go about that because the function only effects the first one?

Comment: if you want to create multiple drop downs then you must wrap your div with a single div and assign a id like
<div id="moreDetails">
<!----
add here your all html tag what you want to
!---->
</div>

Answer (score 0):

To start with more details hidden, you should add `style="display: none;"` to your div; Here's the code:

```js
function toggle() {
  let Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');

  if (Text.style.display == "none") {
Text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
Text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="moreDetails" style="display: none;">

  <h3> 001 </h3>

  <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>

  <h4> N00DS </h4>

</div>

<button title="Click to Show"  type="button" onclick="toggle()">MoreDetails</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, does it also work when you add it to the css of that div?

Comment: I'm afraid not; If you want to toggle it within css, you should define a class and toggle that class in elements classList

Comment: ahh yea of course, that makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: If I need multiple of these drop downs, how would I go about that because the function only effects the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Add display none for div.

```js
function toggle(){
    const Text = document.getElementById('moreDetails');
    Text.style.display = Text.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="moreDetails" style="display: none">

  <h3> 001 </h3>

  <h3> Saturate Radio </h3>

  <h4> N00DS </h4>

</div>

<button title="Click to Show" type="button" onclick="toggle()">MoreDetails</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, If I need multiple of these drop downs, how would I go about that because the function only effects the first one?